# How to copy a file in InnoSetup PreProcessor section?

Tags: inno-setup

I simply want to copy one file to a specified directory before the compilation begins.

**Background:** Im need to create some zip files. One of the files, to be included needs to be copied to the final zip location. (I can not zip it directly from the original location because it would keep the original path in the zip file.

I found out, that the preProcessor action is perfect for this. I tried to use windows copy command but it does not work. 
Is it possible to use a function from CODE section within the preCompiler section? How?
Or is there a completely different way to achieve my target?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I've already suggested to use a batch file for this sort of task, I've made a sample script, which processes all the *.tzs script files in a certain directory and for each of them tries to check if the file have been created (or to be more spefic, if exists). This of course assumes just the very basic use of the *.tzs scripting like shown in the help file. Here it is:

```
#define FindHandle
#define FindResult
#define ScriptFile
#define ScriptLine
#define ScriptHandle
#define ArchiveFile
; unique identifier for the target archive file name property member
#define ArchiveToken ".Archive="
; path to directory, where all the *.tzs script files will be processed
#define ScriptPath "d:\Development\__StackOverflow\14579484\"
; tool, which will be used for the *.tzs file processing mentioned above
#define ScriptTool "c:\Program Files (x86)\TUGZip\TzScript.exe"

; This procedure tries to extract the name of the archive, to be created from
; the line currently read from the just processed *.tzs script file. It first
; tries to search the ArchiveToken constant value in trimmed, space-less line
; of script. If it's found, and the script line contains also two quotes, the 
; file name is stored to the ArchiveFile variable, by which is later checked 
; the file existence after the script execution is done
#sub ParseScriptLine  
  #define SrcPos = Pos("""", ScriptLine)
  #define EndPos = RPos("""", ScriptLine)
  #define ParsedStr = Trim(StringChange(ScriptLine, " ", ""))

  #if (Pos(ArchiveToken, ParsedStr) != 0) && (SrcPos != 0) && (EndPos != 0) && (SrcPos != EndPos)
    #expr ArchiveFile = Copy(ScriptLine, SrcPos + 1, EndPos - SrcPos - 1)
    #expr ArchiveFile = StringChange(ArchiveFile, "\\", "\")
    #if ArchiveFile != ""
      #pragma message "ExecuteScriptFile: ArchiveFile=" + ArchiveFile
      #expr ExecuteScriptFile      
    #endif
  #endif        
#endsub

; This procedure opens the currently processed *.tzs script file and starts to 
; read it line by line to get the file name of the archive to be created
#sub ReadScriptFile
  #pragma message "ReadScriptFile: ScriptFile=" + ScriptPath + ScriptFile
  #for {ScriptHandle = FileOpen(ScriptPath + ScriptFile); \
    ScriptHandle && !FileEof(ScriptHandle); ScriptLine = FileRead(ScriptHandle)} \
    ParseScriptLine
  #if ScriptHandle
    #expr FileClose(ScriptHandle)
  #endif
#endsub

; This procedure is used for the script execution itself, here the TzScript.exe
; tool is called passing the name of the currently processed script file. After
; this tool is done, it's checked if the expected archive file has been created 
#sub ExecuteScriptFile
  #if Exec(ScriptTool, ScriptPath + ScriptFile) == 0
    #if FileExists(ArchiveFile) == 0
      #error The expected archive was not found. Compilation will abort now!
    #endif
  #else
    #error An error occured at script tool starting. Compilation will abort now!
  #endif
#endsub

; This is the file iteration "callback"
#sub ProcessFoundFile
  #expr ScriptFile = FindGetFileName(FindHandle)
  #expr ReadScriptFile
#endsub

; This procedure is used to find all the *.tzs script files in folder, specified
; by the ScriptPath constant path. All the *.tzs files found there are executed 
; by the command line tool specified by the ScriptTool constant 
#for {FindHandle = FindResult = FindFirst(ScriptPath + "*.tzs", 0); \
  FindResult; FindResult = FindNext(FindHandle)} \
  ProcessFoundFile
#if FindHandle
  #expr FindClose(FindHandle)
#endif

[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output
```

Comment: wooow impressive. thanks your effort. although it looks quite more complex and errorprone than my simple batch file, i will give it try. just to see what happens.

thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, batch file is definitely the winner here. I've made this script just out of curiosity and it does more than simple *.tzs file execution. It parses the target archive file name from *.tzs file and verifies if it was successfuly created since `TzScript.exe` tool returns always 0 as a return code (even if it fails), so that's the reason for this verification.

Comment: However, you can still adapt batch file execution from inside of your InnoSetup preprocessor. By something like `#if Exec('c:\YourBatch.bat') != 0` <newline> `#error An error occured...` you can for instance execute the `c:\YourBatch.bat` batch file (whenever you build your setup) and check if it's exit code is not 0. If it's not, then the preprocessor will raise the exception and the overall subsequent compilation will be aborted. So, if you'd add to your batch file exit code returning, you can make sure by this, that you batch file execution succeeded and that acrhives were properly created.

Comment: I am currently not using the ISPP. I am doing preProcessing with InnoIDE_PreProcessor. It is quite simple and can also abort the compilation process when the CopyBatchFile or TzScript fails returns other then zero. I know, it is not an official part of InnoSetup, but it does quite well.

And thanks, I did not know that tzScript alwas return 0. I will check check for the correct creation of files with an other script. Or maybe with a short [code] block to verify that the files exist.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the ISPP [`CopyFile()`](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_copyfile.htm) function.

```
#expr CopyFile("C:\SourceFolder\FileName.exe", "C:\TargetFolder\FileName.exe")
```

Note that it is not possible to use `[Code]` functions from ISPP, but you can use the native ISPP functions and macros.
Calling `Exec()` with the `copy` command also fails as it's a feature of the command processor (`cmd.exe`) rather than an application on its own.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. I tried the following with now luck. Could you please paste me an example?

[InnoIDE_PreCompile]
Name: Exec(CopyFile("C:\OLP\OLP_3_10\Orga\Program V3\bin\app.exe", "C:\OLP\OLP_3_10\Setup\OLP CD 3.10\Orga-Runtime\"));

Comment: I assumed you were using ISPP for which you can use the method above. I have no idea about using the `[InnoIDE_PreCompile]` section.

Comment: @Deanna, that `[InnoIDE_PreCompile]` section is something custom from the ISTool. Christian, precompiler code as it is, you can use in whatever section you want.

Comment: Hi TLama,
thanks for your answer. Call me stupid, but I still have no idea how to copy a file in InnoIDE_PreCompile section. I was google the whole afternoon with no success.

Could you please provide me a more deteiled hint or an example?

Thank you so much

Comment: The `[InnoIDE_PreCompile]` section is a *fictive* section, which is ignored by the InnoSetup compiler. It was introduced by the `ISTool` application probably as some sort of helper section, but in pure InnoSetup has absolutely no meaning. If you want to copy a file using precompiler, simply add such line of code to the beginning of your script. Then when you start building of your setup, precompiler will process that line (copy that file) and then run the compilation of the script itself.

Comment: @TLama I know it exists, I have no idea what it can do in this context.

Comment: @ChristianRockrohr Have you tried the sample I added earlier?

Comment: Sorry, I dit not recognize you sample.
No, it does not work. The compile process stops with no error msg. when it trys to run this code. Any further Ideas?

Comment: I found a quite simple solution :-)
I created a copyfiles.bat with a simple "copy source dest" command inside. It works like a charme. Thanks for all your effort.

Comment: @Christian, maybe I found a problem of your conclusion :-) There must be the target file name specified (at least with the most recent version of the InnoSetup preprocessor), while here was shown just a target folder. Also, don't forget that you have to use build (e.g. by CTRL+F9 key shortcut), not only run to ensure invoking preprocessor.

Comment: @ChristianRockrohr I've also corrected the ISPP syntax. Try again please.

Comment: @Deanna I tried your updated statement with no luck. When hitting CRTL+F9 Compilation window opens, InnoIDE_PreCompiler sections start and then it hangs while shoing the line you posted. Unfortunately without any advises.
Thanks again for you engagement

Comment: Please forget the `[InnoIDE_PreCompiler]` section, and just put it in the top of the script. ISPP has no link to InnoIDE and its custom sections.